# Scala local jar causes scala.runtime error

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have create a scala project, which is dependent on some jar files not available on maven or other remote repository. What I have done is create a folder called 'lib' under the project directory. When I run 'sbt clean' I instantly get an error message. If the jars are removed the clean is successful. Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.
```

Comment: What kind of jars are they? Do they anyhow use a scala reflection? Were they compiled with scala version defined in your project?

Comment: They are actually just java jar files